# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gsl/lib/libgsl.23.dylib

Tags: gsl, dyld, libgsl

I am trying to get a piece of software called [emergent](https://grey.colorado.edu/emergent/index.php/Main_Page) working. It relies on qt and coin, which I've both installed.

But when I try to run emergent, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gsl/lib/libgsl.23.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/emergent
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

gsl 2.6 is already installed on my computer. Also using Mac OS. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
ls /usr/local/opt/gsl
```

see which version of the library you have (I had .25)
then

```
ln -s libgsl.25.dylib libgsl.23.dylib
```

Makes symbolic link between files.
then it worked!