# How to fix the error message "symbol not found in flat namespace '_cblas_caxpy' "?

Tags: python, dylib, anaconda3, libgsl

I am trying to `import msprime` and on MacOS and I get the following traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/filename.py", line 1, in <module>
  import msprime
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msprime/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from msprime._msprime import (
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/msprime/_msprime.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_cblas_caxpy'
```

I had previously been getting the traceback:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/anaconda3/envs/slim-workshop/lib/python3.10/site-packages/msprime/_msprime.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgsl.25.dylib
```

So I used: `ln -s libgsl.27.dylib libgsl.25.dylib`

To create a symbolic link between `libgsl.25.dylib` and `libgsl.27.dylib` (which is the version of the library I have) as per:

[dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gsl/lib/libgsl.23.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106217/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-gsl-lib-libgsl-23-dylib)

I think this might be realted to the problem that I have but have otherwise no idea how what is happening or how to fix it so any help anyone can give me would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem when installing from conda. I uninstalled the conda version and used the pip version instead (`pip install msprime`) which worked for me.